# If $m(E)=m_*(E_1)+m_*(E_2)$ , then $E_1$ and $E_2$ are measurable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

> Suppose $E$ is measurable with $m(E) \lt \infty$ , and $$E=E_1 \cup E_2 , E_1 \cap E_2 \text{is  empty}$$ Show that if $m(E)=m_*(E_1)+m_*(E_2)$ , then $E_1$ and $E_2$ are measurable.

My attempt:
Since $E_2=E-E_1$ , it suffice to prove $E_1$ is measurable . And for $E_1$ , since $m_*(E_1)\le m(E) \lt \infty$ , for any $\epsilon$ , we can find an open set $O$ such taht $E_1 \subset O$ and $m(O)-m_*(E_1) \lt \epsilon$ , but how to show that $m_*(O-E_1)\lt \epsilon$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrarily given and $U_i$, $i=1,2$ be open sets such that $E_i\subset U_i$ and $$ 
m_*E_i\le mU_i<m_*E_i +\epsilon
$$ for $i=1,2$. Since $
E\subset U_1\cup U_2,
$ we have $$
mE \leq m(U_1\cup U_2)=mU_1+mU_2-m(U_1\cap U_2).
$$ This gives $m(U_1\cap U_2)\le mU_1+mU_2-mE<2\epsilon$ by the assumption that $mE=m_*E_1+m_* E_2$. Now, observe that
$$
U_i\setminus E_i \subset \left(U_1\cap U_2\right)\cup \left(\left(U_1\cup U_2\right)\setminus E\right).
$$ This implies
$$\begin{eqnarray}
m_*(U_i\setminus E_i)&\le& m_*\left( \left(U_1\cap U_2\right)\cup \left(\left(U_1\cup U_2\right)\setminus E\right)\right)\\
&\le& m(U_1\cap U_2)+m(\left(U_1\cup U_2\right)\setminus E)\\
&\le& 2\epsilon +m(U_1\cup U_2)-mE\\
&\le& 2\epsilon + mU_1+mU_2-mE<4\epsilon.
\end{eqnarray}$$ Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, it says that $E_i$ are measurable for $i=1,2$.